# Python callback invocation from C++ fails on native site

Tags: python, c++, callback, shared-libraries, ctypes

I have a shared library (DLL) in C++ with some C-style API which I use from Python. There is a function which takes a C callback as an argument. As far as I understood, Python extension module (a separate DLL) is required to do that. This module shall pass a native "proxy" callback to API, then call Python object from that callback. I try do use it as follows (it fails):

```
from ctypes import CDLL
from test_extension import set_python_callback

def callback():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    library = CDLL('test_dll.shared-library')
    set_python_callback(library, callback)
    library.trigger_callback()
```

I'm using Windows 8 x64 environment with Python 2.7.6 (32 bit) and MinGW 32-bit compiler (`mingw32`). Python extension is built by `distutils`. API library can be changed if necessary, however, Python-specific code has to be kept in a separate library.

Here is my code, reduced. All error-checking was removed, however, when performed it showed no errors either from Python API or from Windows API.

API library:

```
/* typedef void (*callback_t)(); */
static callback_t s_callback = nullptr;

void DLL_PUBLIC set_callback(callback_t callback) {
    s_callback = callback;
}

void DLL_PUBLIC trigger_callback() {
    s_callback(); // <--------------------------(1)
}
```

Python extension module function `set_python_callback(library, callback)` takes a `ctypes.CDLL` object and Python callable. It then extracts native DLL handle from the former:

```
PyObject* handle_object = PyObject_GetAttrString(library, "_handle");
const HMODULE handle = static_cast<const HMODULE>(
    PyLong_AsVoidPtr(handle_object));
const native_set_callback_t native_api_routine =
    reinterpret_cast<const native_set_callback_t>(
        GetProcAddress(handle, "set_callback"));
native_api_routine(common_callback);
```

C function `common_callback()` is implemented as follows:

```
extern "C" void DLL_PUBLIC common_callback() {
    // <--------------------------------------- (2)
    PyObject *arguments = Py_BuildValue("()");
    PyObject *callback_result = PyEval_CallObject(s_callback, arguments);
    Py_DECREF(arguments);
    Py_XDECREF(callback_result);
}
```

The error message says:

```
Invoking callback from DLL... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 14, in <module>
    library.trigger_callback()
WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000028
```

Using debug print, I traced the error down to `(1)`. Any code at `(2)` point doesn't execute. The strange thing is, changing the way `common_callback()` call Python code (e. g. passing `Py_None` instead of empty tuple) changes the address in the error message.

Maybe this is somehow related to the calling convention, but I have no idea where it's wrong exactly or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue by registering the thread for GIL as described [in documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#gilstate).

Please note that original API DLL, Python extension DLL, and the script were executed in single-threaded mode and no additional thread had been created, either Python-managed, or not. However, there had been a synchronization issue for sure, because using [Py_AddPendingCall()](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html?#Py_AddPendingCall) also worked. (Using is is discouraged; I found it analyzing `signals` module sources, it lead to the solution above.)

This statement of mine was incorrect:

> Using debug print, I traced the error down to (1). Any code at (2) point doesn't execute.

I was mislead by the fact that *some* of Python API functions still worked (e. g. `Py_BuildValue` or `Py_Initialize`), but most didn't (e. g. `PySys_WriteStdout`, `PyObject_Call`, etc).